# can I customize in odoo apps after deploying to google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, bitnami, odoo-11

I'm new to google Cloud and Odoo ERP,I need to customize in 2 odoo apps Fleet and CRM, Can I customize after deploying odoo via Bitnami Lunchpad to Google Cloud, or I need to customize in local virtual machine, and Can I upload local virtual machine to google cloud or only can deploy odoo to Google via Bitnami Lunchpad.

Can Google endpoints access postgreSQL of odoo server

Any help is welcome, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Cloud Endpoints, it sits in front of your app. You can get the general architecture idea from these links depending on what platform you are choosing to use:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/architecture-overview
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks

Since Google Cloud Endpoints sits in front of your app and forwards requests to your app, your app is still responsible for handling the requests. This would include things like accessing PostreSQL. Therefore, as long as your app can access PostgreSql, using Google Cloud Endpoints should not restrict your usage.